# Is there a way to resample a raster to a lower resolution using a weighted average of constituent pixels?

Tags: python, raster, gdal, projection, resampling

I would like to reproject a raster from WGS 84 (degrees) to ESRI 102001 (meters) while simultaneously resampling the original pixels to a coarser resolution (e.g. .00001 deg to 30 m). I want the final pixel values to be the weighted averages of all high-resolution pixels within the bounds of each final pixel. See the attached rough sketch for an idea of what I'm going for. I want an average of all the small pixels in the red outline (large pixel in different projection).

Concept image:

[image: Concept image]

I have tried gdalwarp using the average resampling method but have found this to be inaccurate. I know I can reproject the original raster to ESRI 102001 at say 3 m resolution first using NN, then resample up to 30 m using the average method, but I would like to be retain as much accuracy as possible and do this all in one step. Is this possible?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: A weighted average isn't the best method for resizing, but depending on your application it might do.